# modify text from static (textfile) layout to responsive (HTML)

Tags: php, html, css, regex, responsive-design

I need to display textfiles as HTML content on different kind of browsers, mailclients and display/device types (Desktop, Mobile, etc).

On small displays, the text-line should break at the end of the screen, but tables should keep there layout.

It's not possible to change the textfile itself, but it's possible to transform the textfile using php, before generation the HTML document.

The Problem is: the textfiles have a kind of layout using spaces, for example to show tables,
like this:

```
This is a part of a textfile, where the
   next line starts with 3 spaces, for example  <- as you can see

In some cases there are    important    spaces insight the text.
sometimes, there are also tables part of the textfiles, build with
spaces, like this:

  Row1      Row2      Row3
  Data       1          2
  Data       ax         547
```

If you simply put this text insight a `<div>` or `<span>` element: The layout get lost, because HTML display multiple spaces as one.

Than I tried the `<pre>` tag to keep the layout. The Problem is: on small display, you have to scroll from left to right to read long lines, which is suboptimal ralated to the usability.

Next i try to change all spaces to protected spaces: `&nbsp;`, using `preg_replace`. This keeps the table layout, but also the  text layout, because every space between every word is now protected.

Finally i tried to convert only multiple spaces, not single spaces, with the same number of protected HTML spaces, using those commands:

```
 //replace odd number of spaces
 $s_text = preg_replace('/   /','&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$s_text);
 //replace even number of spaces
 $s_text = preg_replace('/  /','&nbsp;&nbsp;',$s_text);
```

So the text is "floating" / responsive and some tables keep there structure. But some tables layouts are still  broken.

So my question: how would you "convert" text to make long text lines breaking on the end of the screen and tables hold there layout?

Comment: Assuming that I am a computer, how can I know which text belongs to the table part? Is there any special criteria for me to identify the table part?

Comment: how do you determine which is a long line and which is a table? any logic?

Comment: @invisal This in one of the problems: there is no indicator for an table. But maybe it's possible to define an indicator for an  
paragraph?

Comment: @bansi please take a look at my commend to invisal